# Flutter pub-cache "android does not exist"

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm getting the following error trying to run my Flutter app on an Android emulator. The app runs fine on an iOS emulator. This is on a brand new M2 Mac Mini using Android Studio Hedgehog (there are no AS updates available).

> Basedir /Users/cohen/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics_web-0.5.1+9/android does not exist

This happens for every dependency, not just `firebase_analytics_web`. I've looked at and tried every suggestion regarding this issue I can find (there weren't many). Among them are:

- Invalidating cache and restarting
- Running `flutter pub cache repair`
- Redownloading Flutter
- Ensuring I'm on the latest Flutter, Dart, etc.
- Ensuring I'm using the latest Android Studio

A brand new Flutter project builds and runs just fine. Any differences in the Android configuration I've changed on the error project, but the issue persists.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.3, on macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.16.3 on channel stable at /Users/cohen/Documents/sdks/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0366e0a3f (3 days ago), 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 54a7145303
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/cohen/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A507
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile)  • CB3879FF-6A71-4A26-A31B-42FE8B1E5921 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.71

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by completely replacing my `settings.gradle` file with the one created in a brand new Flutter project, since a brand new project worked. After that change, I was able to build without issues. At the time of this post, the default generated `settings.gradle` is:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
}

include ":app"
```